# how to add additional 5 seconds duration time to wav file using ffmpeg in c#

Tags: c#, audio, ffmpeg, wav, audio-streaming

how to add additional 5 seconds duration time to wav file using ffmpeg in c#.

here is sample code that i used,

ffmpeg -i file1.wav -i file2.wav -c copy file3.wav

I need to add silent duration time to between file1.wav and file2.wav.

how to do it without merging 5 seconds silent wav file.

"file1.wav + 5 seconds silent + file2.wav"

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i file1.wav -i file2.wav -f lavfi -t 5 -i anullsrc
       -filter_complex "[0][2][1]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1" file3.wav
```

`-f lavfi -t 5 -i anullsrc` generates a silent stream of 5 seconds.

---

If you want gaps of varying durations, you can use split and trim filters.

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc -i file1.wav -i file2.wav -i file3.wav -i file4.wav
       -filter_complex "[0]asplit=3[s1][s2][s3];
                        [s1]atrim=duration=2[t1];
                        [s2]atrim=duration=5[t2];
                        [s3]atrim=duration=3[t3]; 
                        [1][t1][2][t2][3][t3][4]concat=n=7:v=0:a=1" 
        file3.wav
```

Or you can generate multiple `anullsrc`

```
ffmpeg -i file1.wav -f lavfi -t 2 -i anullsrc
       -i file2.wav -f lavfi -t 5 -i anullsrc
       -i file3.wav -f lavfi -t 3 -i anullsrc
       -i file4.wav
       -filter_complex
        "[0][1][2][3][4][5][6]concat=n=7:v=0:a=1" 
        file3.wav
```

Comment: I use your mentioned command line but given the error of "lavfi" Input #1, wav, from 'D:\DubmondoTestfiels\test\2.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:01.86, bitrate: 352 kb/s
    Stream #1.0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 22000 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 352 kb/s
Unknown input format: 'lavfi'

Comment: Paste the full console output into your Q.